# How to debug the Angular application in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: angular, debugging, visual-studio-2022

What are the ways to debug the Angular application in Visual Studio 2022? Personally I type debugger; in .ts file.

I tried to set a breakpoint in the GUI but it is stopping at the breakpoint.

I just want to know is there any other efficient way to debug the Angular application in Visual Studio 2022?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the shortcut `[Ctrl] + [Shift] + [D]` then run the application and start debugging.